# How Can I see the Bus Schedule for Bus 150 Bad Ischl to Salzburg

Tags: public-transport, buses, austria, salzburg

We need to take the bus line 150 from Bad Ischl to Salzburg. Where can I see a bus schedule so that I can figure out if our plans are feasible?

Answer (score 3):

You will find this information on the website of the "Salzburger Verkehrsverbund" (SVV): http://www.svv-info.at/en/timetables/trip-planner/